# Widget Settings On Android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

I have one gallery view which hosts the widgets,

I added one widget into gallery view after configuring that widget.

Is there any way that i can get that configured widget's settings and use it later.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little bit vague, since you don't mention what your settings could be.

Typically, for primitive data you could store them in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) which is pretty straightforward.

For more complex settings, you might want to look at alternative storage such as to a file or SQLite

**EDIT:**

Updating my answer since you've changed your question, and now I have a better understanding of what you want.

OK it seems that you want to get access to the configuration of another apps widget. Assuming that the other application stores their configuration in the `SharePreferences`, then you are stuck, there is no way to access another apps' `SharedPreferences`. This has been asked and answered [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030321/android-retrieving-shared-preferences-of-other-application)

At this point, you should be asking yourself the following :

1. What exactly do I want to get from the gallery widget (you're still
   a little vague as to what exactly you want to find out)
2. Is there another approach to fulfilling whatever requirement you
   have

Comment: i don't want to know where and how can i store what i want is way to get configured widget settings

Comment: configured widget settings of what? The settings of your own widget that you're creating?

Comment: yes, settings of third party widget that i am adding it into my gallery view.