# Implement Single Sign on in for Android Applications

Tags: android

I have 4-5 Android applications and I want to implement  Single Sign on for all these apps. So that if user has logged into any one of that apps he won't be asked to log in again for other applications. How can I accomplish it in Android??

Comment: Use SharedPreference across multiple apps?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030321/android-retrieving-shared-preferences-of-other-application

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a SSO requires having a common database holding the user credential information. One way of doing it is implementing your own authentication server which exposes a login, register, reset and forgot password APIs which each of your apps would use to login into the application.

Lets say you are using JWT to maintain statelessness, which means auth server responds with a JWT for every successful login through any android app.

So your launcher activity in each of your app should not be login but the dashboard or whatever the user sees after login. In the on_create of the dashboard, check if there is an existing jwt available in the shared preferences. If there is one, go ahead with the dashboard. But if there isnt one, goto login activity and let the user login first. Once logged in, preserve the jwt in shared preferences for the other apps to use it. You need to make sure that all the shared preferences are using the same namespace to access the jwt.

To make it more effective, you can implement a library module for login, regd and forgot password to be included into each app and you would have that part for all the apps ready. The XML files for three activities can be included into the lib itself and app will load them from the lib file if it doesnt find it in the app drawables.

Now coming to server part, implementing your custom auth server, say using OAuth2 is one way but to make it easier, there are 3rd party solutions like Stormpath or CAS which would provide such a service. May be you can find one which is free too.

Instead of JWT, you could use userId (primary key in the user database) to identify if the user is logged in or not.

Another point to consider is if the application server for each of these apps, if they have one, are using JWT or userId to respond to app requests and based on that auth server communication token should be decided. Needless to say, that application server and the auth server should also communicate among them to sync user information for app. This would be the same even if you are using a 3rd party auth server which would talk to a single database holding the entire user information but you might need to work on syncing your application server with 3rd party auth server

However, the tricky part is in logout and reset password and change password. I am not talking about the logout process if JWT is used, which has its own challenges to meet, but I am talking about the logout when SSO is used. If the user logs out from one of the apps you need to decide if the user has to be logged out from the rest of the apps or not. Both can be handled though but usually it would be a single sign out for ease of implementation and it would provide a good UX too.

Also, if any of these apps has a website version and the user changes or resets password from the website, you need to make sure that user logs in again on the device when he first uses the app after the change. However this logic has to be managed entirely on the server side inside the auth server.

Though your question is related to android app only, you might have to implement a server for that and modify the appl server too for each of the app. There might be a chance that this might not be your question essence entirely, but your actual requirement might help me to help you implement this.