# Not able to access/clear Sharedpreference value from other app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to access shared preference value created in one application from other applications I'm able to retrieve the data only if I close the app from the task manager else the changes are not reflecting.

**First Activty:**

```
btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get The User name and Password
            String userName = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
            String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_READ_WRITE, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE + Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
            Editor prefsPrivateEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            prefsPrivateEditor.putString(KEY_READ_WRITE, "test");
            prefsPrivateEditor.commit();

To clear:

clear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_READ_WRITE, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE + Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
            Editor prefsPrivateEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            prefsPrivateEditor.clear();
            prefsPrivateEditor.commit();
        }
    });
```

**In other App I'm retrieving like this:**

```
Context otherAppsContext = null;
                try {
                    otherAppsContext = createPackageContext("com.example.app", 0);
                } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                }
                sharedPreferences = otherAppsContext.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_READ_WRITE, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE + Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
                String authToken=sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_READ_WRITE, "WORLD READ WRITE EMPTY");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), authToken, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: why `Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE + Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` can you try using just `Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE` ?

Comment: i tried that too still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit different code, but looks like a working one

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6030399/995020

Comment: Thanks Max :)  but i'm able to retrieve the value only when i close the app manually!!