# Android : SharedPreferences not updated

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, aidl

My 2 android applications communicate throught a AIDL file :

> Application A  <== AIDL ==> Application B (service)

Application A calls methods of Application B (service) that returns some JSON information. However, If user is not logged in application B, null is returned.

(service in application B)

```
//first : get info
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(Consts.SP_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
String userId = mPrefs.getString(Consts.PREFS_USER_ID, "");
String userPass = mPrefs.getString(Consts.PREFS_USER_PASS, "");

//then check is valid (remote server)
if (dao.exist (userId, userPass)){
 return "MY_JSON_INFO" ;
}else{
 return false;
}
```

If null is returned, "login" activity in Application B is launched from Application A.

(Aplication A)

```
if(json == null){
  Intent intent = new Intent("jp.app.LOGIN_ACTIVITY");
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

User log in (Application B), data are saved in SharedPreferences (Application B) and activity is closed (back to Application A).

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = a.getSharedPreferences(Consts.SP_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();     
prefsEditor.putString(Consts.PREFS_USER_ID, id);
prefsEditor.putString(Consts.PREFS_USER_PASS, pass);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

When re-trying to call methods of the Application B, login information saved few seconds ago are not available and null is returned.

I have tried without success with prefsEditor.apply() .

If I restart application B, login data will be loaded....

Please let me know if further information are needed.
Thank you

Comment: Editor prefsEditor = prefsEditor.commit(); change these line only to \ prefsEditor.commit();

Comment: I have updated my message, sorry

Answer (score 1):

After a long struggle, I have at last managed to get my updated preferences.

When calling getSharedPreferences,  I use Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS flag.

[MODE_MULTI_PROCESS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_MULTI_PROCESS)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By reading your comment i can give you a quick solution:

The easier way is to simply terminate your activity (A) before calling the login activity inside your service.

```
if(json == null){
  Intent intent = new Intent("jp.app.LOGIN_ACTIVITY");
  startActivity(intent);
  this.finish();
}
```

So that, when you fill in the login form and call back the activity A it will read the new shared preferences!

Comment: If I first login with B application and then start A application, it works well (I mean JSON is returned).

Comment: and your issue is: you launch A. if there isn't any sharedprefs with login data it goes to B for login. Once logged in it move back to A but there isn't any data loaded until you kill and reopen A. right?

Comment: Login information is checked in the B application (service). If login information is present and correct, it will return JSON info. If not, it will return null. In this case, login activity (application B) will be called

Comment: I understand this, but once logged in B, it move back to A. once moved back to A it doesn't get any data until you restart A. is that right?

Comment: perfectly right ! in other words, I cannot get updated data. But if I restart A application, I can login.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually When log in information is validated, Login activity is closed and user goes back to the A application... So I cannot "finish" it.

Comment: I made a mistake in my previous message.. I can't can any data until I restart B application (not A)

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to access the shared preference of other `application`.

You should try :: [Android: Retrieving shared preferences of other application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030321/android-retrieving-shared-preferences-of-other-application)

Comment: Ok, try the answer in that link provided by 
danhnn.uit

Comment: Thank you. I don't have to share preferences since service of application B access to sharedPreferences of application B. Application A don't access directly to preferences.