# How to send a SharedPreference from an App to another?

Tags: java, android

Hey I have an app(Let's call it app A) on the playstore and I want to replace it with another completely different app(Let's call it app B) but I need some of the `SharedPreference` in app A to be sent to app B but I don't know how to send data from an app to another does anyone know how or if it's even possible. I tried creating a file containing the data on the sdcard but I don't like that idea since it is not secure, so if you anyone has a better idea please help me.

Comment: Yes by package name.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030321/android-retrieving-shared-preferences-of-other-application

Answer (score 0):

I think best variant for you would be sending an intent with all preferences you want to store from the first app. In second app you need to register intent receiver that will get all data from intent and store it in preferences. Here is an [article](https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/) that described this approach more detailed.