# Use Shared Preferences of other application

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I found the same questions on stack and used this way

```
   public void setProgramAllProgress(int all){
        SharedPreferences prefs = CApplication.getAppContext().getSharedPreferences(BASE_PATH,
                Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("all", all);
        editor.commit();
    }


    public int getProgramAllProgress(String packageName){
       Context con=null;
        try {
            con = CApplication.getAppContext().createPackageContext(packageName, 0);
            SharedPreferences pref = con.getSharedPreferences(
                    BASE_PATH, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            int data = pref.getInt("all", -1);
            return data;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("Not data shared", e.toString());
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

But it doesn't work. I get the context from package, but SharefPrefs are always empty.

Comment: I don't think you can access SharedPreferences of other applications.

Comment: @iturki you can, but only if the application has set them as WORLD_READABLE, which is deprecated. So no one should use this, but it is possible.

Comment: @F43nd1r if it's possible why it's not working. If it's deprecated what should i use instead?

Comment: @JenyaKirmiza for one-way data sharing use Content Providers. For two-way communication use one of the possible IPC methods (google it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030321/android-retrieving-shared-preferences-of-other-application) i think you have to do the following:

In Application1:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("demopref",
                    Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("demostring", strShareValue);
            editor.commit();
```

and, in Application 2:

```
try {
    con = createPackageContext("com.sharedpref1", 0);
    SharedPreferences pref = con.getSharedPreferences(
    "demopref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String data = pref.getString("demostring", "No Value");
    displaySharedValue.setText(data);
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("Not data shared", e.toString());
}
```

Tell me if it works!:)

EDIT: anyway, [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) are the best way to do it

EDIT 2: if you strongly want to use sharedPrefs, try adding in manifest this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.hello"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" 
android:sharedUserId="com.example"> //<-- this line
```

EDIT 3: [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk_content-providers--mobile-5549) is a guide on how to use ContentProvider :)

Comment: I'm doing the same. it's not working. I can see only prefs saved by current application.

Comment: I didn't want to, but i think i'm gonna need ContentProvider

Comment: @JenyaKirmiza try with the last edit i posted, maybe it works

Comment: Thanks. Now it's working. I have one more question: is it hard to use ContentProvider for this purpose? I didn't use it earlier

Comment: @JenyaKirmiza Unfortunatly i never used them before too, i've just read on the web that they are necessary for this purpose, I edit with a guide i found :)

Answer (score 1):

That would require the application which´s SP you want to access to use [MODE_WORLD_READABLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE) when writing data to its SP. This **constant is deprecated** and Google **strongly recommends not to use** it:

> Creating world-readable files is very dangerous, and likely to cause security holes in applications. It is strongly discouraged; instead, applications should use more formal mechanism for interactions such as [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html), [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), and [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

So if the app you want to access is not developed by your own I assume that its SPs are private and if it´s your own app than you should find a different way for sharing data.

Comment: what way? ContentProvider? or create some file on storage?

Comment: I never happend to implement a ContentProvider (so honestly I do not know all their features) but I assume that you should go with them, since they are the recommended way and were built for exactly that purpose. SharedPreferences are also just XML-files in your app´s data-directory.

Comment: anyway thanks for help. I'll try to do it the right way