# Store in specific folder SharedPreferences flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I've read an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938853/sharedpreferences-to-a-custom-path-android) on how to do this in android, and an [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47978857/how-to-store-sharedpreferences-in-specific-folder-and-get-it) for android too, but does anyone know how to specify a folder for the SharedPreferences data to be stored in?

In my case, a device receives data from multiple devices, so I'd like to store that data under different folders (one folder per user). Currently they all sit in the default `data/data/com.[]/shared_prefs`.

If you want some code, this is my current SharedPreferences class:

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class MySharedPreferences {

  Future<Set<String>> getKeys() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final value = prefs.getKeys();
    print("got ${value.length} results");
    return value;
  }

  Future getForm(String key) async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final value = prefs.getString(key) ?? 0;
    print('read: $value');
    return value;
  }

  deleteForm(String key) async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.remove(key);
    print("deleted $key");
  }

  void saveForm(String json, String title) async{
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = title;
    final value = json;
    prefs.setString(key, value);
    print('saved $value');
  }

  void saveName(String name) async{
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = 'userName';
    final value = name;
    prefs.setString(key, value);
    print('saved $value');
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
MySharedPreferences().deleteForm(element);
```

Comment: Not possible...

Comment: I think that It is not possible as you can't save multiple things (in your code it is possible) because normally it is not accepting.