# How to get value from Shared Preference of other app from other app in android?

Tags: android

I have two app let suppose "AppOne" and "AppTwo",In AppOne I have some value stored in its shared Prefrence like "String "name",What I want to get this value from "appTwo".How can I do that

code of AppOne Sahred Preference:-

```
private SharedPreferences m_Preference;
private SharedPreferences.Editor m_Editor;
private final String MY_PREF="AppData";

public PreferenceHelper(Context context){
    this.m_Preference = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREF,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    this.m_Editor = m_Preference.edit();
}
/*Saving String value......*/
public void saveStringPreference(String key,String value){
    m_Editor.putString(key,value);
    m_Editor.apply();
}
public String getStringPreference(String key){
    return m_Preference.getString(key,"");
}

/*Saving int value........*/
public void saveIntegerValue(String key,int value){
    m_Editor.putInt(key,value);
    m_Editor.apply();
}
public int getIntPreference(String key){
    return m_Preference.getInt(key,1);
}
```

And in MainActivity I save that value:-

preferenceHelper = new PreferenceHelper(getApplicationContext());

```
    preferenceHelper.saveStringPreference("Name", "ABC");
```

Comment: Implement some API in App One that App Two uses: `ContentProvider`, remote `Service`, etc.

Comment: MODE_PRIVATE means the data is private to the ap. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/6030399/4818247

Comment: since you use Context.MODE_PRIVATE, you should not have access to this preferences from the other apps.

Comment: I change to Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE, Now what to do

Comment: @Nitin give us some feedback about the answers

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that. **`SharedPreferences` are local for the package of the app** and can not be accessed directly from the outside (security reasons, most likely).

If you want other apps to be able to get some data from your app (`SharedPrefs` or any other data) you will need to define a `ContentProvider`, an `BroadcastReceiver`, `Service` or an external (web) api :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write a file instead of using sharedPreferences to store some data.
With this way, you can reach the data from another android application.

To write a txt file

```
public void writeToFile(String data)
{
    // Get the directory for the user's public pictures directory.
    final File path =
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
        (
            //Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/YourFolder/"
        );

    // Make sure the path directory exists.
    if(!path.exists())
    {
        // Make it, if it doesn't exit
        path.mkdirs();
    }

    final File file = new File(path, "myText.txt");

    // Save your stream, don't forget to flush() it before closing it.

    try
    {
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        myOutWriter.append(data);

        myOutWriter.close();

        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    } 
}
```

to read the file :

```
public String readTheFile(){
//*Don't* hardcode "/sdcard"
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

//Get the text file
File file = new File(sdcard,"myText.txt");

//Read text from file
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        text.append(line);
        text.append('\n');
    }
    br.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    //You'll need to add proper error handling here
}
 return text.toString();
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution, but you assume that the OP is looking for a way to so this and not for a 'hack' to access the data of other apps

Comment: @Kelevandos, It depands on what type of data should I store in Android. I like to use to sharedprefrences or writting a file to store small strings etc. Wrinting/reading the file is much easier than using contentProvider in this case.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but only if you are the developer of both apps that you want to communicate