# Android SharedPreference cannot get retrieved by another App correctly

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In Android, I have two Apps sharing user ID. App A creates a sharedPreference and App B can read it in its activity's onResume(). The question is: I modified the preference in A and then go to B, I find the value is still the old one -- I am sure the preference has committed because I can see the new value in Pref.xml. I have to exit B and re-enter it, then I can see the new value. Would you please point me why? where is the buffer? how to refresh the preference mandatory? Thanks for your comments in advance :)

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6030399/6950238) answer.

Comment: are you sure to re-load shared prefs in App B after modified in app A?

Comment: @Vlad Matvienko How does one reload them?

Comment: init them again - `prefs = getSharedPreferences(...)`

Comment: Actually, I do prefs = getSharedPreferences(...) in onResume, but it still retrieve the old value although the value has been changed by App A.