# How to share preferences with all build flavors of my android app

Tags: android, build, sharedpreferences, android-build-flavors

I have an app with 3 build flavors and 3 applicationIds for different ways to use the app.  How can I share the preference values among all flavors of the app so if user sets the prefeences under app.flavor1 the same values are available in app.flavor2?

My code:

```
mPreferences = getSharedPreferences("app_settings",MODE_PRIVATE);
void persistSettings(){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firstRun",false);
        editor.putInt("voltage", mVoltage);
        editor.putInt("duration",mDuration);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

These preferences behave independantly for each app build flavor.
Each app uses the same settings but just a different UI. 
Perhaps there's a better aproach than 3 separate app flavors ?

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11949750/3319074