# Content Provider to store single string

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-contentprovider

I have to store a single authentication string(shared preference) inside content provider so that I can use that authentication sting by one more different application.

I found so many examples for SQLite database with the content provider but in my case table is not needed.

can anyone please help me how to **store a simple string in content provider and get it by other app.**

Thank you

Comment: Using SQLite or maybe a world readable share preference are the two options which come to mind ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030321/android-retrieving-shared-preferences-of-other-application)).

Answer (score 0):

[you might want to check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11949750/6640982)

Shared preferences are one way to go about it . You see when you set a preference you can choose the option of making it readable by other app . This is how you can set a shared pref in one app and access it in another , I would provide code but the answer i have tagged is exactly what I would do. Also I dont know your specific case but sqlite for just this purpose will add alot of headache . Even if you decide to go for that you shopuld check out room database [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room)

Comment: Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE is for global data access, i don't want to make  string value available for all other apps.