# How do I use sharedpreferens between two applications?

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

X and Y two applications. They are not subclass of each other. I want to write a string from X application to Y with SharedPreferences and read it from Y application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: Retrieving shared preferences of other application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030321/android-retrieving-shared-preferences-of-other-application)

Comment: Do you really mean applications? or Activities? Since you mention subclasses..

Comment: Caution: The MODE_WORLD_READABLE and MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE modes have been deprecated since API level 17. Starting with Android 7.0 (API level 24), Android throws a SecurityException if you use them. If your app needs to share private files with other apps, it may use a FileProvider with the FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION. For more information, also see Sharing Files.

Comment: Yes 2 apps. @RobCo

Answer (score 1):

Create Shared preferece data in first application set its mode to `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`

```
SharedPreferences mSharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("Prefs_First", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPrefs.edit();
editor.putString("name", etName.getEditableText().toString());
editor.putString("password", etPassword.getEditableText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

To access that data from the other app, try this,

```
Context mContext = createPackageContext("com.sample.globalsharedpreference", CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);

SharedPreferences firstAppSharedPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("Prefs_First", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

String strName = firstAppSharedPrefs.getString("name", "");
String strPassword = firstAppSharedPrefs.getString("password", "");
```

Note that `com.sample.globalsharedpreference` is the package name of the first app.

Comment: java.lang.SecurityException: MODE_WORLD_READABLE no longer supported

Answer (score 0):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.firstapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" 
android:sharedUserId="com.example">
```

Also you might have to replace Context.MODE_PRIVATE with Context.CONTEXT_RESTRICTED

```
myContext = context.createPackageContext(
                        "com.example.secondapp",
                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 shared= myContext.getSharedPreferences("fileName", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: What if I want to change the application after I publish it?