# How to share flutter sharedpreferences between flutter apps?

Tags: android, flutter, sharedpreferences

With native android it is possible to read other native native application shared preference.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("packagename", MODE_PRIVATE);
String value = prefs.getString("key, null);
```

How do we do it between flutter applications?
It seems that there is no function to call getSharedPreferences with `packagename` parameter

Comment: seems this feature is not supported but exists in native : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11949750/5220303