# Retrieve value from appA to appB using intents

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have two apps (appA and appB). I want to retrieve a single value stored in `appA sharedPreferences` and use it in appB. Can I do that using intents?. I just need to do this once (on first install of appB).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that adding `.putextras()` to your intent and then getting them with `getExtras()` on appB (after checking if they are present at all).

check this answer for reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/5265952/10637400

Answer (score 0):

Use Intent to launch appB in appA

```java
// Launch appB in appA
Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(appB_PackageName);
intent.putExtra("key","value");
startActivity(intent);
```

Or read sharedPreferences in appB
[Android: Retrieving shared preferences of other application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030321/android-retrieving-shared-preferences-of-other-application)